# Restrict the run of workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow

I have field that has attachment. And i have a workflow which triggers when item created or modified.
How can i restrict the running of workflow when an attachment is added

Comment: It's a good question, someone can probably answer it, but not me.  I thought I'd suggest uploading the attachments to a separate document library, I do this kind of thing all the time with e.g. project task lists.  You can upload related documents to a separate place and use lookup columns to make a link between the Task List and the Documents.  It might be worth testing out.

Comment: I checked but u cant make attachment field as lookup in List

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether Attachment equals yes in designer workflow. If it is Yes then stop the workflow else run the workflow.

For e.g.

[image]

Comment: For first Time it worked but after then second tym it is not even giving email after editing other field

Comment: Can you post your workflow screenshot?

Comment: You may want to add a second column to check if the Attachment column was the same as last time the workflow ran. If it’s not the same, an attachment was added or removed. If it is the same, don’t do anything cuz nothing was added/removed.